# How to switch the Detail View Controllers without touching a Master View Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a Master and Detail View Controllers in iPad Storyboard. Also I have a AddUserController.xib View. I need to open a AddUserController.xib view from the current Detail View Controller. Code of the Button, which should do that, but it doesn't, is:

```
NSArray *viewControllers;

AddUserController *addUser = [[AddUserController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddUserController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.navigationController, addUser, nil];
self.splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;

[self presentViewController:addUser animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Why are you not pushing into a nav controller or using a popover?

Comment: I don't want to touch a .xib file.

Comment: Why would you have to? And why the reluctance?

Comment: Everything is working, except this. I thought, it is easier… just replace a view in detail view. If I will touch more - a lot of problems will be.

Comment: Is the detail view in a nav controller? If not, use a popover. Otherwise you have to worry about restoring all of the state to get back to the original detail view...

Comment: Detail View is NOT in a Nav Controller.

Comment: So present a popover. It sounds like the add user controller is transient anyway.